# how works "break" within a while-loop in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a simple Question: when there's a "break"-command within a while-loop, does the program finish the lines until the end of the while-loop and then breaks its repetition or does it jump to the first line after the while-loop when executing the "break" - command?

Comment: It jumps to the end of the loop immediately. But you could have written a program that tests this behavior in almost as little time as you spent asking the question. Don't be afraid to experiment!

Comment: @Jon: Or looked it up in any C++ reference or tutorial. You can't learn the language by asking about keywords one at a time.

Comment: sry, i'll never post stupid questions like this again. i was simply lazy and didn't want to interrupt my work with online search. Thank you guys.

Comment: I think that asking a question on SO is a really slow way for getting an answer for this type of quesition. I'd just write a program and check it, on your place.

Comment: What did your C++ reference book say about the `break` statement?

Answer (score 4):

It jumps immediately out of the containing `while` loop (§6.6.1):

> The `break` statement shall occur only in an *iteration-statement* or a switch statement and causes termination of the smallest enclosing *iteration-statement* or switch statement; control passes to the statement following the terminated statement, if any.

Consider [the following example](http://ideone.com/sEM7C4):

```
while (true) {
    break;
    std::cout << "Never gets here" << std::endl;
}
std::cout << "Jumps straight to here" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

it does the following thing

The break statement terminates the execution of the nearest enclosing do, for, switch, or while statement in which it appears. Control passes to the statement that follows the terminated statement.